# Attempted import error: 'event' is not exported from 'd3'

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to add Event and tooltip on my React App using D3

I am getting the following error

**Attempted import error: 'events' is not exported from 'd3' (imported as 'd3').**
the d3 version is  "d3": "^6.2.0",
it seems it is not able to find events from the library

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import ReactFauxDom from 'react-faux-dom';


        let toolTip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#cccccc')
            .style('opacity', '0')
            .style('padding', '10px')
            .style('border', '1px #000000 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')



.on('mouseover', (d) => {
                tooltip.style('opacity', 1);
                tooltip.html(d)
                    .style('left', (d3.events.pageX) + 'px')
                    .style('top', (d3.events.pageY) + 'px')
            })
            .on('mouseout', (d) => {
                tooltip.style('opacity', 0);
            })
```

Comment: d3.event has been removed from d3v6, the event is now passed directly to the listener.

Comment: @AndrewReid Great , what is my alternative in this code where I am trying to get the coordinates from the events

Comment: The linked answer does provide some more info, but if you used `function(d) { d3.event.x })` in v5, you can use `function(event,d) { event.x  })` in v6.